# Importing XML data into ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, xml

I hasve an XML document originated from this [site](http://overpass-turbo.eu/). It contains location and data for resturants and bars. How can I import those locations theirs data and meta-data to arcmap?

I am still relatively new to arcgis.

Comment: You should parse the xml to extract the data, i.e. coordinates and attributes; that load the table into arcmap. Also have a look on this tool [import Xml](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000014s000000)

Comment: What format is the XML, for example is it GML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do as below:
Since this map uses openstreet map as a basemap so follow as below-

Run the query> Export result> Download geojson>add ineteroperability connection in arc map and add exported geojson> add basemap(openstreet map)

[image]

N.B In this case (arcmap 10.1) you need interoperability extesion installed in arc map
for 10.2 onward there is a tool called JSON To Features (Conversion) use this to convert this geojson to feature (or use interoperability)

Several format export is possible e.g as geoJSON,as GPX,as KML,raw data- all these format can be imported into arc map using interoperability connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool in arc map called Import XML Workspace Document. The data must be imprted into a geodatabase. You can try that tool. If that does not work, you can try converting your xml file to a different format that can be used by arcmap, perhaps gpx or excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If that XML file from Overpass Turbo is fully equivalent to *.osm files, which I suspect so, than you should have a look at ESRI's free Open Source "ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap". It has an option to load *.osm files, and create Feature Classes inside a (File) Geodatabase in the process, including support for complex multipolygons and buildings.

See here (ESRI also recently released a 10.3 version):

**ArcGIS Editor for OSM, 10.2.x Desktop**

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=16970017f81349548d0a9eead0ebba39